# Why am I not able to deploy my build? It says my artifact quota limit has been reached

Tags: github, github-actions

My GitHub account shared storage gets full in a day even though I have not switched on my system. Somehow my artifact quota got full on 1st January 2024 and no one touched the account since 30th December 2023. Below is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

I tried to set my spending limit to $1. I don't think that's helping. While deploying, it still gives me the error saying unable to artifact quota full.